# How to override a method of a base class which is an input of a function?

Tags: c++, overriding

I am trying to override a method in a code I am using to learn about this but I didn't succeed, what am I missing?

Here some code to reproduce my issue:

`my_class.h`

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H


class Base {
    public:
        Base();
        virtual ~Base();
        virtual double evaluate(double x);

};

double call_evaluate(Base funct, double x);

#endif
```

`my_class.cpp`

```
Base::Base () {}
Base::~Base () {}
double Base::evaluate(double x){
        std::cout << "evaluate base\n";
    return 0.0;
};

double call_evaluate(Base funct, double x){
    return funct.evaluate(x);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "my_class.h"
#include "iostream"


class Derived: public Base{
private:
    double value;

public:

    Derived(double value){
        this->value = value;
    }

    double evaluate(double x) override{
        std::cout << "evaluate derived\n";
        return this->value*x;
    }

};


int main(){

    Derived problem(6);
    double a=problem.evaluate(2);
    double b=call_evaluate(problem, 2);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", expected = 12\n";
    std::cout << "b = " << b << ", expected = 12\n";

    return 0;
}
```

`Output`

```
evaluate derived
evaluate base
a = 12, expected = 12
b = 0, expected = 12
```

Comment: `call_evaluate` takes the object by value, performing object slicing if it is a derived class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Change the signature of `call_evaluate` to `double call_evaluate(const Base& funct, double x);`

Comment: @NathanPierson what you propose is not working, when I compile I get the error `error: passing 'const Base' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|`

Comment: Oh, right. You'd also want to make `evaluate` a `const` member function, since it's not supposed to change the internal state of a `Base`. So `virtual double evaluate(double x) const`, and then corresponding changes to the `evaluate` definition and in `Derived`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to change `call_evaluate` to receive the first argument by reference.

```cpp
double call_evaluate(Base& funct, double x);
```

For the reason why your program behaves like it does, see below.

Your coding style suggests you come from a Java-like background. You must make yourself aware of a very important point about C++. In the function declared below, both arguments are passed by value, not by reference.

```cpp
double call_evaluate(Base funct, double x);
```

"by value" in current C++ parlance means the source object is going to be copied, that is, an unnamed copy of the original object is going to be created then passed to the function. "by reference" means the source object is merely going to be referenced or aliased, that is, the function receives a reference or alias to the same object.

From a Java-like programmers perspective, this should look like the pseudo-code below.

```java
auto tmp0 = funct.clone();
auto tmp1 = x.clone();
call_evaluate(tmp0, tmp1);
```

In C++, you may achieve the effect of "by reference" by explicitly marking the parameter type as a reference type with the `&` declarator.

```cpp
double call_evaluate(Base& funct, double x);
```

Doing "by reference" with reference types require no special notation on the callers side.

```cpp
call_evaluate(func, x);
```

Additionally, in C and C++, you may achieve the effect of "by reference" by passing object addresses as parameters. You do this by explicitly marking the parameter type as a pointer type with the  `*` declarator.

```cpp
double call_evaluate(Base* funct, double x);
```

Calling "by reference" with a pointer type requires the caller to use the unary `&` operator to obtain the object's address.

```cpp
call_evaluate(&func, x);
```

Now, what is the problem with your program? You are "slicing" a polimorphic object.

Since `call_evaluate` receives the first parameter "by value", C++ will generate a "copy" expression to create a new, temporary, unnamed object from the source object.

The target type for this "copy" expression will be the type of the parameter, `Base`. In other words, C++ will generate an expression for the purpose of creating a new, temporary, unnamed object of the `Base` type from the source object.

Since this temporary, unnamed object has type `Base`, you will readily see how it polimorphically behaves just like any `Base` type should.

This is called "slicing" since it "slices" the object, that is, it creates a new object from just the `Base` part of the source object.

You may benefit from doing these experiments:

Declare `call_evaluate` as a pure virtual function. If there is no definition in the base class, what will this program do? For more information, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class

Forbid `Base` copy constructor and copy assignment operator with the `= delete` special syntax. If copying `Base` is not allowed, what will the compiler do? For more information, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions

Answer (score 1):

This is a polymorphism problem.
In your example, the Base class is the parent class and the Derived class is the child class.

A child class has attributes that it inherited from the parent class. So it is possible to pass an object of the child class into an object of the parent class due to the property of inheritance. (Attention, the reverse is not possible. ) However, by passing an object of the child class into an object of the mother class, you lose all the information relating to the child class.

In your example, the `call_evaluate` function takes an object from the parent class as a parameter. but you are trying to pass an object from the child class. This loses the child class information.

To solve your problem, you must add a reference to your function parameter such as:

`double call_evaluate(Base &funct, double x)`.

You can also pass a pointer like:

`double call_evaluate(Base *funct, double x)`.